# Permanently tick use default box

Tags: default.xml

[image]We would like to permanently tick the 'use default box' for all of our products.

Can someone elaborate on how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Use single store mode https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/store-mode-single.html?

Answer (score 0):

Set single store mode

**1.On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.**

**2.Under General, scroll down to the bottom of the page and expand the Single-Store Mode section.**

**3.Set Enable Single-Store Mode to Yes.**

[image]